# Summing the total characters not included the white space in all rows Python

Tags: python, pandas

If this code could get the total words separated by white-space in 41,000 rows of **column2** in **df**:

```
sum(list(map(lambda x : len(x.split()), df['column2']))))
```

what would be the code for summing the total of all the characters (exclude the white-space) from all those rows?

This is how dataframe **df** look like:

```
column1           column2                                          column3
amsterdam         hay instagram plastic i become srt week          2015
rotterdam         letmebe yess yezz become  i week insta           2000
the hague         keyboa sna but oia yeq leek                      -
```

Comment: Couldn't you just take the length minus the count of whitespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total number of all characters in the column, a one-liner might look like this

```
sum(list(map(lambda x : sum(len(y) for y in x.split()), df['column2'])))
```

Comment: pretty summed up what i'm looking for @toxicity

Comment: This seems unidiomatic. Why not use the features provided by Pandas? @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani Why is your original code like that in the first place?

Comment: @AMC what do you mean by _unidiomatic_ ? 

I just want to check how many characters are there in my dataframe so that I could estimate the cost that I would get in google translate API

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani Where does the data come from? Are they each a different piece of text to translate?

Comment: @AMC it's Flickr tags data. So I put every tags, description, title of a place ID into one column called **keywords**. So now I need to translate all that rows of keywords in column **keywords**. But there is a limit to google translate API, and it counts per character not per words to translate.

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani Oh, you group the description and title etc. together?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `str.findall`:

```
df.columns2.str.findall(r'[^\s]').str.len()

0    33
1    31
2    22
Name: column2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: *premature-optimization-note* - this is much faster than the other method according to my `timeit` results!